# Handlebars SWAG library

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm new in Handlebars and I'm trying to use SWAG library for custom helpers but unsuccess.
For example I try to display in my file.handlebars  *{{lowercase "BENDER SHOULD NOT BE ALLOWED ON TV"}}* and I get the error *Error: Could not find property 'lowercase'*
I ran *npm install swag*

my app.js is:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , path = require('path')
  ,Swag = require('swag')
  , handlebars = require('handlebars');

var app = express();
var engines = require('consolidate');
app.engine('handlebars', engines.handlebars);

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/dashBoard', routes.getDashboard);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Thank in advance for your help

Alcudia

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that `consolidate` package returns it's own locale copy of Handlebars. As so, it is not the Handlebars you required, and it is not a global Handlebars onto which swag is applied.

To schematise: `require("Handlebars") !== require("consolidate").handlebars`

So, my guess now is that you'll need to register the swags helper on the consolidate handlebars instance. (And there, I checked Swag code source and I don't thinks that's possible ATM)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

> Swag.registerHelpers(Handlebars);